# FCM for sending multiple notifications in an efficient manner

Tags: php, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am retrieving push message data from database and want to send notifications in one go instead of using while loop in php.

Code:

```
$pushMessageDetails->DbQueryPrepare('CALL procGetAllPushMessages()');
$pushMessageDetails->DbQueryHit();
while ( $pushMessageDetails->DbQueryFetch() )
{
  //having few checks and forming postData
  //connecting using curl_setopt and executing

}
```

Comment: Did you see the Firebase documentation on [sending messages in batches](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-a-batch-of-messages)?

Comment: Here I want to send different notifications to different devices.

Comment: Each app on each device has its own device token, which you pass to in the `token` to that call. That is no different to targeting a single device with a single call though, so I recommend trying to get it to work based on the documentation I linked and some of the many examples out there.

Comment: After reading the documentation, it mentions sending same notification to multiple devices (registration id array) or sending in topics (here also same notification content). I want to send different notification (specific content) to different users by making a single connection. In short I want to send a batch of notifications and need to connect to FCM only once per batch.

Comment: If you check [this code sample](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#node.js_5) in the link I shared, you'll see that it sends a different message to each token. I recommend giving it a try, as it seems to match exactly what you're asking for.